# WooCommerce product variations are not showing, while these are in database

Tags: wordpress, variables, woocommerce, product

We are facing an issue with woocommerce variations, please note there is

No wordpress update,
No plugin update

The variations are present in database tables for each product but not showing when editing the product, also at frontend price and dropdown are showing, but when I trying to select an option showing error "Sorry, this product is unavailable. Please choose a different combination.".

When I am creating the variations from available attributes its starts working fine.

Comment: Have you replaced DB?

Comment: No, I have not database is same it was earlier

Comment: "not showing when editing the product", then what it shows when editing the product? What happened before this error appeared? Because at some it worked isn't?